# keychain or icloud

Tags: iphone

hi i have a second hand iphone 4 my partner brought off his sister for me christmas prezzy. this phone asks me for icloud password and i askedmy in law for it this morning this phone says its incorrect but my sisternlaw said its the only password she uses for everything so i dont know what to do. i cant get apps or anything really without this password either so i really need help. im also useless with tech like this lol so i need like more help than most lol just wanted to ask how i can change my icloud password or keychain